# How set ExifInterface into Thumbnail Image?

Tags: android, android-image

I have an Image and a Thumbnail. I want set `ExifInterface` of the Thumbnail the same `ExifInterface` of the Image. I use this code, but it's not working:

```
ExifInterface of = new ExifInterface(lastFile);
int orientation = of.getAttributeInt(
ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0); //orientation=6
ExifInterface exifi = new ExifInterface(strFileThumnail);
// exifi.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0) =0 
exifi.setAttribute(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION,String.valueOf(orientation));
exifi.saveAttributes();
// exifi.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0) =6
```

After setting, I use this code to get the information:

```
exifi = new ExifInterface(strFileThumnail);
// result still : exifi.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, 0) =0
```

How set `ExifInterface` into Thumbnail image?